# Storage.set does not seem to be working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angularfire2

I am trying to store a list of objects from a firebase list in ionic 2, using [Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) `import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage'` . When I set the storage however the stored array is empty.

```
this.api.getDataListAsPromise(`/programLists`).then(programLists => {
    let programListArr = [];
    new Promise(res => {
      res( forEach(programLists, value => { programListArr[value.$key] = value; }) );
    }).then(() => {
      console.log(programListArr);
      this.storage.set('programLists', programListArr);
    });
  });
```

The `console.log(programArr)` returns

[image]

Which is exactly what I want to store in local storage.

However when I `this.storage.set('programLists',programListArr);` . It sets it as an empty array

[image]

Can someone maybe explain why this is happening and if it is possible to set the created object literal in the local storage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't store object in `storage.set()` but you can do this:

```
this.storage.set('key', JSON.stringify(value));
```

and then get it:

```
this.storage.get('key').then((value) => {
    let json_value = JSON.parse(value);
});
```

Comment: It is not an object. It is an Object Literal, and also you definitely can store object. my "user" is stored as an object using `this.storage.set`

Comment: yeah i have .. does not work , i get a return of `"[]"`

Comment: can you test `programListArr[0]` and see whats apen?

Comment: That will display nothing has i have changed the object key to the $key value returned from firebase

Comment: omg .. i just had to make `programListArr` an object and not and array ... thanks for bouncing ideas